# How to concatenate 3 parallel dense layers?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, concatenation, keras-layer

I want to concatenate 3 parallel layers each with `Input(shape=(1,))` for multiclass classification.

```
                                            _______
input_1(feature[10000,0])----> dense ----> |       |
                                           |       |
input_2(feature[10000,1])----> dense ----> | Merge |----> output(12)
                                           |       |
input_2(feature[10000,2])----> dense ----> |_______|
```

It takes a feature matrix with a shape of [10000, 3].

My current code to do this is:

```
num_features = 3
num_outputs = 12

def create_model():
    # Input layers for each feature
    inputs = [Input(shape=(1,)) for i in range(num_features)]
    
    # Hidden layers for each feature
    hidden_layers = [Dense(8, activation='relu')(input_layer) for input_layer in inputs]
    
    # Concatenate the hidden layers
    concatenated = Concatenate(hidden_layers)
    
    # Output layer
    output = Dense(num_outputs, activation='softmax')(concatenated)
    
    # Create the model
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)
    
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

# Create a KerasClassifier
keras_classifier = KerasClassifier(model=create_model, verbose=0)
keras_classifier.fit(np.array_split(features.transpose(), num_features), labels, verbose=0)
```

However, I get an error.

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [3, 10000]
```

I tried to transpose the feature data but I still get the error.

Comment: I am not sure how this would work with functional API. But if you use OOP API instead this is pretty trivial using tf.concat() along the first axis. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat

Comment: Is it possible to for you to give me a short example using tf.concat? Thank you for the reply.

Comment: Something like this: outputs = []
for i, layer in enumerate(self.layers): 
    y = layer(X[:, i])
    outputs.append(y)
tf.concat(outputs, axis = 1)

Comment: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/OKUA1/84be0b3231904701026b894359a2ac03/raw/73afc917d8ed31aecb8746eebc4d46faff725613/concat.py